# Is there a Dart equivalent to the Regex Capture class in C#?

Tags: regex, dart

I am trying to replicate this [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture?view=netframework-4.7.2) that uses the Capture class in Dart. I noticed that Dart doesn't seem to have the concept of Captures within a group.

Here's the MSDN example source for posterity:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "Yes. This dog is very friendly.";
      string pattern = @"((\w+)[\s.])+";
      foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Match: {0}", match.Value);
         for (int groupCtr = 0; groupCtr < match.Groups.Count; groupCtr++)
         {
            Group group = match.Groups[groupCtr];
            Console.WriteLine("   Group {0}: {1}", groupCtr, group.Value);
            for (int captureCtr = 0; captureCtr < group.Captures.Count; captureCtr++)
               Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", captureCtr, 
                                 group.Captures[captureCtr].Value);
         }                      
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Match: Yes.
//          Group 0: Yes.
//             Capture 0: Yes.
//          Group 1: Yes.
//             Capture 0: Yes.
//          Group 2: Yes
//             Capture 0: Yes
//       Match: This dog is very friendly.
//          Group 0: This dog is very friendly.
//             Capture 0: This dog is very friendly.
//          Group 1: friendly.
//             Capture 0: This
//             Capture 1: dog
//             Capture 2: is
//             Capture 3: very
//             Capture 4: friendly.
//          Group 2: friendly
//             Capture 0: This
//             Capture 1: dog
//             Capture 2: is
//             Capture 3: very
//             Capture 4: friendly
```

Here's my attempt to replicate it in Dart:

```
  final RegExp _regExp = new RegExp(r'((\w+)[\s.])+');
  final String _input = "Yes. This dog is very friendly.";

  var matches = _regExp.allMatches(_input);

  for   (int i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    var match = matches.elementAt(i);
    print('Match $i');
    for (int j = 0; j < match.groupCount; j++) {
      var group = match.group(j);
      print('\tGroup: $j $group');
    }
  }
```

But that gives these results:

```
Match 0
    Group: 0 Yes.
    Group: 1 Yes.
Match 1
    Group: 0 This dog is very friendly.
    Group: 1 friendly.
```

Notice the last group (Group 1) in Match 1 only contains 'friendly'. Is there a way in Dart to enumerate multiple captures within a single group like the MSDN example outputs?